# show and hide MenuBar on Android using QML

Tags: android, qt, qml, menubar

I am trying to show the Qt MenuBar (I think it is the same as the ToolBar) on android. Not finding any other options I tried to show and hide it from a checkbox using this code:

```
onCheckedChanged: {
        if (checked) {
            appWindow.menuBar = menuBar
        }else {
            appWindow.menuBar = null
        }
}
```

The complete code is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/abcf5a7d42dfa3cda9c7).

The App crashes if I do that. How else could I do this?